# Can I add a colored button to a UIToolbar?

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, uitoolbar

It seems like I can't add any buttons that contain colors in a UIToolbar, they always get replaced with a white mask. How can I add a colored image to a custom button in a UIToolbar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can, but its not really a uibarbuttonitem.

here is the link.

http://fredandrandall.com/blog/2011/03/31/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-uibarbuttonitem/

PS.

If you want to have an IBAction for that button, then call it on valuechanged event.

Answer (score 1):

No, I dont think you can directly. It looks like it has to be as you said.

You might be able to hack things though by putting your image over the toolbar's image and letting the touch events pass through it by tweaking the hit testing.

Answer (score 1):

Without using private API's, you can't.  Apple will block your app if you use the private API's, so you might as well construct your own control and use that.

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at the UIApperance protocol this is very useful for customising the look and feel of many of the UI elements. You can change a specific item or every instance of that item using the static method.

```
[[UIToolBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]]
```

This would change every instance of a UIToolBar in your app blue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom toolbar, where you can use any toolbar background and colored images: http://github.com/marichka/Custom-UIToolbar